# Close app after closing last fragment

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am writing an app with Xamarin.Android and MvvmCross. I am using fragments and have a "content container" design where I show the fragments in my `content_frame` view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Everything works, and I can navigate through my app by showing/closing the fragments in my `content_frame`, but when I close the last fragment, instead of closing the app, it shows a blank screen instead. I reckon I can fix this in my `MvxAppCompatViewPresenter` class but I don't know how? I currently don't have anything in my view presenter:

```
public class ViewPresenter : MvxAppCompatViewPresenter
{
    public ViewPresenter(IEnumerable<Assembly> androidViewAssemblies) : base(androidViewAssemblies)
    {
    }

    public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        base.Show(request);

    }

    public override void Close(IMvxViewModel viewModel)
    {
        base.Close(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Here is the first fragment:

```
[MvxFragmentPresentation(typeof(LoginViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame, true)]
[Register("myapp.droid.fragments.LoginSelectionFragment")]
public class LoginSelectionFragment : BaseFragment<LoginSelectionViewModel>
{
    protected override int FragmentId => Resource.Layout.fragment_login_selection;
}
```

Comment: What does your `MvxFragmentPresentation` look like, specially the third bool parameter `AddToBackStack`? Additionally, do you always have the same fragment at the start of your stack? If so, is this starting fragment used anywhere else that it would need to be added to the backstack?

Comment: I included the first fragment in my app. If I set the third bool parameter to false, I won't be be able to come back to it. It won't always be the first fragment that I show, and it's not used anywhere else that it would need to be added to the backstack.

Comment: One of the approaches you can use, is to not add the fragments that are starting fragments to the backstack. The idea there is that for the first fragment you would rely on the activity being added to the backstack. Essentially, the first fragment and the activity could then be considered the same with respect to the backstack, eliminating the blank screen. However, this would only work if the starting fragments do not need to be added to the backstack in the same activity context later.

Comment: I just changed the third parameter to `false` and I don't get the blank screen anymore... I don't know why it didn't work the first time I tried that...thanks!

Comment: Cool, I'll put it in answer, I was not to sure how your backstack was working, so I thought there maybe some adjustments needed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the approaches you can use, is to **not** add the fragments that are starting fragments to the backstack by setting the `MvxFragmentPresentation` property `AddToBackStack` to `false` (`false` is also the default if no parameter is passed).

The idea there is that for the first fragment you would rely on the activity being added to the backstack. Essentially, the first fragment and the activity could then be considered the same with respect to the backstack, eliminating the blank screen.

However, this would only work if the starting fragments do not need to be added to the backstack, with in the same activity context, later in the navigational flow. In future versions of MvvmCross you would easily be able to overcome this limitation via the updated [`IMvxOverridePresentationAttribute`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/2483).